# How to use different argument types across different pallets

Tags: pallet

I am trying to use one pallet function inside my own pallet... but the argument types have problems...

```
  #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_vesting::Config {
    ...}
  #[pallet::call]
  impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
    ...
    pub fn vested_transfer(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        target: <T::Lookup as StaticLookup>::Source,
        locked: BalanceOf<T>,
        per_block: BalanceOf<T>,
        starting_block: BlockNumberFor<T>,
    ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
        let vesting_info = pallet_vesting::VestingInfo::<BalanceOf<T>, BlockNumberFor<T>>::new(
            locked,
            per_block,
            starting_block,
        );
        let is_valid = vesting_info.is_valid();
        ensure!(is_valid, "invalid vesting_info");
        let res = pallet_vesting::Pallet::<T>::vested_transfer(origin, target, vesting_info);
```

Then the error message for the 3rd argument vesting_info:
... vesting_info... expected pallet_vesting::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency

Then I tried this to cast the vesting_info type:

```
vesting_info as pallet_vesting::Config::Currency
```

... error message: use fully-qualified syntax: `<Type as pallet_vesting::Config>::Currency`

Then I tried this to fix that the 3rd argument:

```
vesting_info as <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as pallet_vesting::Config>::Currency,
```

... error message: use of undeclared crate or module `pallet`

Then I tried this to fix that the 3rd argument:

```
vesting_info as <<T as Config>::Currency as pallet_vesting::Config>::Currency,
```

... error message: the trait `pallet_vesting::Config` is not implemented for `<T as pallet::Config>::Currency`... an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object

Then I tried this to fix that the 3rd argument:

```
vesting_info as <<T as Self::Config>::Currency as pallet_vesting::Config>::Currency,
```

... error message: the name `Config` is defined multiple times; cannot find associated type `Currency` in `Self::Config`

how to use "pallet" or different pallet function argument types ?

Comment: I have two questions:
1. Do you want to fork the `vested_transfer` function or just use this within your pallet?
2. Are you tightly coupling your pallets Config with the one of `pallet_vesting::Config`? https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/pallet-design/tight-coupling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and easy way to solve your issue would be to [tightly couple](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/pallet-design/tight-coupling/) your pallet's `Config` trait with the one of `pallet_vesting`. This way, you would not have to define the `Currency` trait in your Config.

```rust
type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as pallet_vesting::Config>::Currency as Currency<
        <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
    >>::Balance;

pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_vesting::Config {
   // your custom associated types
}
```

Then you can simply call the `vested_transfer` like so

```rust
#[pallet::weight(10_000)]
pub fn your_custom_extrinsic(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    target: <T::Lookup as sp_runtime::traits::StaticLookup>::Source,
    vesting_amount: BalanceOf<T>,
    per_block: BalanceOf<T>,
    lock_period: T::BlockNumber,
) -> DispatchResult {
    let vesting_info = pallet_vesting::VestingInfo::<BalanceOf<T>, T::BlockNumber>::new(
        vesting_amount,
        per_block,
        lock_period,
    );
    pallet_vesting::Pallet::<T>::vested_transfer(origin, target, vesting_info)
}
```

Without tight coupling, it is more complicated. On a high level, you would need to provide a conversion from your `pallet::Config::Currency` trait to the one of `pallet_vesting::Config::Currency`.